# check if no key is pressed

Tags: c++, arduino, windows-10, console-application

I am maiking a CLR Console Application to controll a robot. I am using `cki.Key == ConsoleKey::UpArrow` to check if button is pressed and then send message to the robot. I want to stop the robot when no keys are pressed. How can I find out if no keys are pressed?

I was trying `Console::KeyAvailable == false`, but then I need to press another button to stop the robot.

What I've tried is below:

**With `Console::KeyAvailable`**:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
do{ 
    cki = Console::ReadKey(true);
    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey::UpArrow) 
    { /* send message forward*/ }
    else if (Console::KeyAvailable == false) 
    { /* send message STOP*/ }

}while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey::Escape);
```

**UPDATE code with `_kbhit()` (still not working)**:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
do{ 
    cki = Console::ReadKey(true);
    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey::UpArrow) 
    { /* send message forward*/ }
    else if (_kbhit() == false) 
    { /* send message STOP */ }

    while (_kbhit())
        getch();

}while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey::Escape);
```

**New Idea**:

```
while (true)
{                       
    if (Console::KeyAvailable==1)
    {
        cki = Console::ReadKey(true);
        if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey::UpArrow)
        {
            Console::WriteLine("Forward");
        }
        if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey::Escape)
        {
            Console::WriteLine("Escape");
            break:
        }       
    }
    else
    {
        Console::WriteLine("STOP");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a keyUp event available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you change the loop to `while (true)` and inside loop check if the key is available using `Console::KeyAvailable`, if the key is not available, send message stop, if it is available, read the key and check which key it is, if it is `UpArrow`, send message forward. If it is `Escape`, break the loop.

```
ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
while (true){

    if (Console::KeyAvailable){
        cki = Console::ReadKey(true);
        if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey::UpArrow){
            // Forward
        }
        else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey::Escape){
            break;
        }
    }
    else{
        // Stop
    }   
}
```

And maybe add some kind of sleep or something there, so your program doesn't always send stop whenever the pressed key is being processed and isn't in the keyboard buffer yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using event listenr fuction like _kbhit it can check when key is being pressed and when it's is being released and can be used as conditions to the type of signal u want to send. You will need to include : conio.h
This should work better:

```
do{ 
    int key;
    if (_kbhit())
        key = getch();
    else
        key = 0;
    if (key==72)
    {
        // send message forward
    }
    else if (key=0) 
    {
        // send message STOP
    }
}while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey::Escape);
```

This code should work better

Comment: I added code with _kbhit, but is still not working. Could you look at it at say waht is wrong?

Comment: I would suggest initializing a variable through _getch(). And use it as a condition of your else if statement and just change it's value to 0 every time you want to clear the buffer, i hope it'll work

Comment: Try using following code:

   do{ 
   int key;
  while (_kbhit()){
  `      key = getch();`
   if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey::UpArrow)
   { // send message forward}
    }
   key = 0;
   else if (key) 
   { // send message STOP }

}while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey::Escape);`

Comment: @DavinderpalCheema you should include the code that you're suggesting in your answer. Please don't post it in a comment.

Comment: Will check it now

Comment: Mind formatting it? Please indent your code. It should be readable.

Comment: Now It sends "STOP" all the time :(

Comment: When i am holding UpArrow it  is "STOP" ... and "FORWARD" for 1 ms and "STOP" again

Comment: I've updated my code again i'll see if it doesnt work when i get to my computer

Comment: Nothing is happening

Answer (score 0):

you can use _kbhit() function in c++. _kbhit is equal to 1 if any key is pressed. You have to clear the _kbhit buffer else it will remain 1. Method for clearing is character = getch(); This will save the last entered key in character which you can compare and decide which action to perform on which key.

Comment: Do I need to include something, so I can use _kbhit() ?

Comment: I tried it and it doesnt work. Here is part of my code:

Comment: I tried and it doesnt work. Here is part of my my code: `
   
   do{
   if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey::UpArrow)
   {
    // send message
   }

   else if (_kbhit() == false)
   {
    // send code to stop
   }
   while (_kbhit())getch();
  }while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey::Escape); 
   `